# Unable to load Parse Image using picasso library. "imgUrl is cannot be resolved to a symbhol"

Tags: android, google-maps, infowindow

I have been struggling the past few days with loading an image inside an infowindow in google maps. I believe I am not referencing the url from parse correctly. Can anyone please help me or guide me on how to get the parse image into the infowindow? this is the snippet for that code. (NOTE) I can load an image into the infowindow with resources but not from parse. (I beliebe the problem is I am not referencing the right item) Thanks in advance.

PS: This line of code: imgUrl cannot be resolved to a symbol

```
 @Override
    public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap googleMap) {
        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        this.googleMap = googleMap;
        googleMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter() {

            // Use default InfoWindow frame
            @Override
            public View getInfoWindow(Marker arg0) {
                return null;
            }

            // Defines the contents of the InfoWindow
            @Override
            public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {


                //icon.setImageResource(R.mipmap.back_vision_fade);

                ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Places");

                View v = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.maps_infowindow, null);
                v.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams((int) (mapFragment.getView().getMeasuredWidth() * .9), LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.title)).setText(marker.getTitle());
                ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.desc)).setText(marker.getSnippet());
                ImageView icon = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView5);

                Item item = new Item();

                try {
                    List<ParseObject> objects = query.find();
                    for(ParseObject obj : objects){
                        ParseGeoPoint point = obj.getParseGeoPoint("location");
                        if(obj.getParseFile("icon")!=null) {
                            item.setIcon(obj.getParseFile("icon").getUrl());
                            //item.downloadIcon(context);
                            item.setIcon(obj.getParseFile("icon").getUrl());
                            Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(imgUrl).into(icon, new MarkerCallback(marker));

                        }
                    }
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                }

                return v;

            }
    }

    );
```

Comment: Where is imgUrl defined ?

Comment: That is one problem. I took that from an example I found. UPDATE: I just tried something and it seems to get the icon from parse by changing imgUrl to item.getIcon which is defined in my Item class. But its a default icon and it is not gettting the corresponding icon. Changed to this:

Comment: Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(item.getIcon()).into(icon, new MarkerCallback(marker));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(obj.getParseFile("icon").getUrl()).into(icon, new MarkerCallback(marker));
```

Comment: Yes this kind of works but I am still displaying a default image and not the correct image. I have an array of images inside parse that are associated with diferent events. I want to display the correspondent image. Right now it only displays one single image. I

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of this ?

Comment: Also it maybe a good idea to log all obj.getParseFile("icon").getUrl() in order to verify that urls parsed correctly.

Comment: Please take a look at my Item class. perhaps i am not downloading the image? http://pastebin.com/D62jWYJD

Comment: Maybe I am not referencing the correct parse table item?

Comment: Add Log.v(obj.getParseFile("icon").getUrl()); just before Picasso call, so you can verify urls.

Comment: tried to log.v but I get an error when doing so "Cannot resolve method (java.lang.String)

Comment: I used System.out.println and this is what the stack trace shows me:


06-26 15:56:18.409 11030-11030/com.farr.android.farrapp I/System.out: A VER VER VER VER VER VER VER VER VE VRcom.parse.ParseFile@1dc45e4d
06-26 15:56:18.409 11030-11030/com.farr.android.farrapp I/System.out: A VER VER VER VER VER VER VER VER VE VRcom.parse.ParseFile@3de5cd02

It seems that the files are different but I still get the same image in my infowindow

Comment: UPDATE: Image being downloaded to phone comes from parse. I believe the problem is that I am not referencing a list or getting the length of the same list. I am marking this as answered because the original issue was resolved. Thank you @AntonMalmygin and everyone else who helped me on this issue.

Comment: The problem is that I am not referencing the list of items in parse and android is simply taking the first image it finds, not the one assigned to that info. I am marking this as answered because the original issue was resolved. Thank you @AntonMalmygin and everyone else who helped me on this issue. EDIT

Comment: Yes, Thank you! But because life is life, I have another issue. I am able to get the image from parse, but I have a table that stores files for each prase table item, the image I am getting back is not the correspondent to the data. Would you be able to help? :) Thanks